# What happens when i try to read a file when it's in saving/overwriting process?

Tags: process, operating-system, save, filesystems, background-process

Let's say i have a file with multiple texts and i try to read it in code. Let's say it takes 15 seconds to read the file. When my code starts reading and in 7th second another process tries to save or overwrite it. What happens in that situation? Does os allow to save/overwrite it and if yes, does my reading process would have any problems?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the OS. Each OS has a different behavior.

On Windows, the files can be locked when they are opened, the program has to opt in for shared accesses it can tolerate: reads, writes and/or deletes-renames. The program can also lock a portion of a file, which will temporary deny access to that portion for other programs.

On Linux, the shared access is the default. File locks exist, but they usually only prevent other locks - not the direct read or write without a lock. Mandatory locks (the ones, that do prevent reads and writes) may be disabled on the filesystem - they slow down all file accesses. Deletion and renaming are not considered file accesses at all (they are considered writes to the parent directory). After deletion, the file will still be accessible for programs that have opened it, but it will be gone for good after the file is closed.

In general, reads and writes are not atomic, and the read can see some combination of the written data and the original data. For example, if the file contains `123` and the someone writes `ABC`, the read should expect `123`, `ABC`, `1B3`, `A2C`, and some similar options (but not `123ABC`, `BC1`, or similar - no rearranging the positions).